# bring attention to old questions which recently went on bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I had asked a question two months ago and it received 6 upvotes. Two answers were provided and I accepted one of them. That answer also received 4 upvotes. I recently reviewed the topic of the question and I found the given answer not convincing. After bringing the matter to the attention of the user who had answered it, he decided to remove his answer. I then started a bounty. However, the question is still buried among the old questions. I also edited the question but I still can not see it among the recent questions. Question: how else can I bring the question to the attention of the users?

Comment: Using the share button on the question, and promoting the question in various forms of social media is a good way to gain attention if done right. I accidentally earned a gold badge by sharing a question on social media.

Comment: Putting a bounty on the question will periodically bump it to the top. It will not stay there just because of a bounty. However, it will also be on the "featured" list, together with the other questions with open bounties.

Comment: Editing brings it on top, too.

Comment: meta.SO: [Does offering a bounty still bump questions to the front page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111714/does-offering-a-bounty-still-bump-questions-to-the-front-page)